# Using cmake to copy files to multiple dependent target binary folders

Tags: cmake

I have a project system (multiple users) in cmake that use ctest to run regression tests. One of the libraries in the project have data files that are required by the library, like plugins and config files. I then have X other executable targets (ctests) that depend on this library. I have been trying to setup the library `CMakeLists.txt` to copy files to the binary output directory of each target that use the library. I have tried `add_custom_command` and `file` to copy the files. I can get the files copied to any directory once. But it is still the library that decide where the files are copied to. How can I turn this around and define generic "data" files as part of the library target (or custom target) so that these files are copied along with the library binary itself to the dependent target binary directories?

**lib/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_library(mylib ${mylib_sources})

file (COPY datafile DESTINATION $<TARGET_FILE_DIR,mylib>)
```

**app2/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(app1 ${app1_sources})
target_link_libraries(app2 mylib)

add_test(NAME app1_test COMMAND app1)
```

**app2/CMakeLists.txt**

```
add_executable(app2 ${app2_sources})
target_link_libraries(app2 mylib)

add_test(NAME app2_test COMMAND app2)
```

Now that I run ctest it will execute app1 and app2. Both of these are statically linked with the mylib library. But datafile is not copied to the app1/app2 binary directories. I don't want to do the copy in each appX (can be 100s) and there can be multiple libraries with data files. So I would like to add datafiles in the library CMakeLists that get copied to all binary directories that use it.

Comment: I do not understand. Which file do you want to copy where and when and on what does it depend on? `I have been trying` Please show the code from your tires. Why and how your tries failed? `it is still the library that decide where the files are copied to` What does it mean? How does it happen? How the library "decides"? Does the library copies the files? What kind of data are those? What is the structure and dependency between targets you are describing. Please share the code. Please create an [MCVE].

Comment: @KamilCuk, I added a sample if that helps

Comment: You can't use generator expression in `file(COPY`. Use them with `add_custom_command`. What about doing something along `add_custom_command(TARGET app1 POST_BUILD ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy datafile $<TARGET_FILE_DIR....>)`

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm not at my dev machine. But yes I know, this was written from top of my head. But I have tried custom_command with generator expressions and file using current binary dir etc. But this only get the files to the library binary directory. I need some way to describe data file dependencies of the library so they are copied to the appX binary directories.

Comment: `to the library binary directory` so just use `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:app>` right? You can't make dependencies on child targets that will use your library. I mean, the user of your library will have to consciously write some code that will specifically copy the file into his app directory - you can't "force" that. You could provide a cmake function for such user for ease of use.

Comment: ok, so I would need to attach a list of files to a target property of each library `add_content_files(mylib, ${content_files}) -> set_properties(TARGET mylib PROPERTY mycontentfiles ${content_files})`, allowing me to have a helper function that check for this property on all libraries of a target `copy_content_files(app1) -> foreach library -> copy get_property(mycontentfiles) to CURRENT_BIN_DIR` for example.